# Proportion unitary method

Tags: numerical-methods

3 kitchen assistants can prepare 10kg of vegetables in 30 minutes. How long would it take 15 assistants to prepare the same amount?

Comment: Hint: it will take 1 assistant 90 minutes to prepare 10kg.

Answer (score 0):

$3$ assistants $\implies$ $30$ minutes

$15$ assistants (= $5$ times more assistants) $\implies$ ($5$ times less time =) $6$ minutes

**Note** these are the beautiful questions that shows the large difference between theory and practice. Suppose we have $150'000$ assistants, then (using the same argument) it should take $30/(150'000/3)=30/50'000 \approx 0.0006$ minutes to cook $10$kg pastas. This is not totally realistic.